# How I can set display name to dropdown list?

Tags: c#, forms, infopath

For a dropdown list in infoPath form, I have both value and display name.
for example, 0=book, 1=car (0-1 - value, book-car -display name).

I wonder how I can set (select) display name in c# .

For Value:

```
xNavMain.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ddlist", xNameSpace).SetValue("car");
```

How about display name? How I can select `"car"`?

Answer (score 1):

I think `yourdropdown.SelectedItem.Text;` should do the trick.
I'm not sure though my C# got a bit rusty.

Comment: there is no dropdown.selecteditem. It's infopath forms, we work xNavMain.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ddlist", xNameSpace).SetValue("car"); somethink like that..

Comment: oh i read over the infopath part, cant help you with that sorry. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Is your dropdown populated using a data source? If, so you can get the value from the data source and then set the dropdown.

```
XPathNavigator nav = DataSources["MyXmlData"].CreateNavigator();
nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("/data/option[./display='car']");
nav = nav.SelectSingleNode("./value");

XPathNavigator docNav = this.CreateNavigator();
docNav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ddlist", NamespaceManager).SetValue(nav.Value);
```

My XML data source in this case is:

```
<data>
    <option>
        <value>0</value>
        <display>book</display>
    </option>
    <option>
        <value>1</value>
        <display>car</display>
    </option>
</data>
```

If it's hardcoded, you have to hardcode the value as well.

```
docNav.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:ddlist", NamespaceManager).SetValue(1);
```

Comment: Yes, the xpath expression will just be different.